Stripe invoice period is not correct
I'm integrating Stripe with my SaaS and I'm calculating the quota using the valid payment period, but Stripe always returns the period as being from the 70s, even though I have defined the plan as monthly, it comes with the beginning through the webhook and end on the same day in the 70s
// webhook

import Stripe from "stripe";
import { headers } from "next/headers";

import {
  processWebhookInvoiceSuccess,
  processWebhookSubscription,
  stripe,
} from "@/services/stripe";

export async function POST(req: Request) {
  const body = await req.text();
  const signature = headers().get("Stripe-Signature") as string;

  let event: Stripe.Event;

  try {
    event = stripe.webhooks.constructEvent(
      body,
      signature,
      process.env.STRIPE_WEBHOOK_SECRET
    );
  } catch (error: any) {
    console.error(`Webhook Error: ${error.message}`);
    return new Response(`Webhook Error: ${error.message}`, { status: 400 });
  }

  switch (event.type) {
    case "customer.subscription.created":
    case "customer.subscription.updated":
      await processWebhookSubscription(event.data.object);
      break;
    case "invoice.payment_succeeded":
      await processWebhookInvoiceSuccess(event.data.object);
    default:
      console.log(`Unhandled event type ${event.type}`);
  }

  return Response.json({ ok: true }, { status: 200 });
}


Sounds like a datetime / ticks issue. Can you share your body and event, without the sensitive bits?

https://gist.github.com/natanfeitosa/8aef22c8bf8660f65811ec60e8375d38

How did you get your created and other times? Those look like the defaults from the stripe api docs. You should be setting those similar to date.getTime().  E.g., new Date().getTime() returned 1716611623138 for me. Then when I try to turn that back into a date: new Date(1716611623138) it is logged out as Fri May 24 2024 23:33:43 GMT-0500 (Central Daylight Time).  If you look at the difference in length between the ones in your event and this sample, you can see how much bigger mine is. This is Time at which the object was created. Measured in seconds since the Unix epoch.

Thank you, I already solved it. I changed the approach a little, I don't know if it's the most correct way, but it worked
async function processWebhookInvoiceSuccess(obj: Stripe.Invoice) {
  if (!user) throw new Error("invoice user can't find");

  await prisma.user.update({
    where: { id: user.id },
    data: {
      latestInvoiceStart: new Date(obj.lines.data[0].period.start * 1000),
      latestInvoiceEnds: new Date(obj.lines.data[0].period.end * 1000),
    },
  });
}

